# Converting javascript date to java sql date error

Tags: javascript, java, jackson

Javascript created date:

```
"created_at": new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')
```

In java I am trying to map it to java.sql.date inside pojo class:

```
public class Comment extends Model{

    private Date created_at;

    public Date getCreated_at() {
        return created_at;
    }

    public void setCreated_at(Date created_at) {
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }
}
```

I get error when I map it using preparedStatment:

```
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
pst.setDate(1, newComment.getCreated_at());
```

**Error:**

```
   org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.sql.Date from String value '2017-03-27 09:28:40': not a valid representation (error: Can not parse date "2017-03-27 09:28:40": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:m
m:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@1ce91e6; line: 1, column: 16] (through reference chain: com.soul.seeker.models.Comment["created_at"])
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.weirdStringException(StdDeserializationContext.java:243)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer._parseDate(StdDeserializer.java:577)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer$SqlDateDeserializer.deserialize(StdDeserializer.java:1086)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer$SqlDateDeserializer.deserialize(StdDeserializer.java:1077)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1863)
        at com.soul.seeker.serviceImpl.CommentServiceImpl.createComment(CommentServiceImpl.java:39)
        at com.soul.seeker.Application.lambda$main$7(Application.java:80)
        at spark.ResponseTransformerRouteImpl$1.handle(ResponseTransformerRouteImpl.java:47)
```

Comment: Why not remove the slice and replace you are doing on the javascript end? Seems it is unnecessary....

Answer (score 2):

You can use long to receive a time value.
javascript:

```
{"created_at": new Date().getTime()}
```

and 
java bean (you can deal with the getter method):

```
public class Comment extends Model{

private Long created_at;

public Date getCreated_at() {
    return new Date(created_at);
}

public void setCreated_at(Long created_at) {
    this.created_at = created_at;
}
```

}

Comment: ok when I retrieve the date, I need to reformat it back to date format right?

Answer (score 1):

add adnotation to field created_at

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

check your library version
for example i have, it's works:

> jackson-annotations-2.8.7
>   jackson-core-2.8.7 jackson-databind-2.1.4

Comment: Installed all the maven packages. still same